# How to evaluate minHashLSH in Spark with scala?

Tags: apache-spark, evaluation, minhash, lsh

I have a dataset of academic papers and it has 27770 papers (nodes) and another file (graph file) with the original edges with 352807 entries long. I want to calculate minHashLSH to find similar documents and predict links between tow nodes! Bellow you can see my try about implementing this on spark with scala. The problem which I am facing is that I don't know how to evaluate the results!

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
println("MinHash LSH")
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR) // show only errors


val ss = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("neighbors").getOrCreate()
val sc = ss.sparkContext

val inputFile = "resources/data/node_information.csv"

println("reading from input file: " + inputFile)
println

val schemaStruct = StructType(
  StructField("id", IntegerType) ::
    StructField("pubYear", StringType) ::
    StructField("title", StringType) ::
    StructField("authors", StringType) ::
    StructField("journal", StringType) ::
    StructField("abstract", StringType) :: Nil
)

// Read the contents of the csv file in a dataframe. The csv file contains a header.
var papers = ss.read.option("header", "false").schema(schemaStruct).csv(inputFile)

import ss.implicits._
// Read the original graph edges, ground trouth
val originalGraphDF = sc.textFile("resources/data/Cit-HepTh.txt").map(line => {
  val fields = line.split("\t")
  (fields(0), fields(1))
}).toDF("nodeA_id", "nodeB_id")

println("Original graph edges count: " + originalGraphDF.count())
originalGraphDF.printSchema()
originalGraphDF.show(5)

val t1 = System.nanoTime // Start point of the app

val nullAuthor = "NO AUTHORS"
val nullJournal = "NO JOURNAL"
val nullAbstract = "NO ABSTRACT"

papers = papers.na.fill(nullAuthor, Seq("authors"))
papers = papers.na.fill(nullJournal, Seq("journal"))
papers = papers.na.fill(nullAbstract, Seq("abstract"))

papers = papers.withColumn("nonNullAbstract", when(col("abstract") === nullAbstract, col("title")).otherwise(col("abstract")))
papers = papers.drop("abstract").withColumnRenamed("nonNullAbstract", "abstract")
papers.show()

papers = papers.na.drop()
val fraction = 0.1

papers = papers.sample(fraction, 12345L)
//    println(papers.count())

//TOKENIZE

val tokPubYear = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("pubYear").setOutputCol("pubYear_words")
val tokTitle = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("title").setOutputCol("title_words")
val tokAuthors = new RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("authors").setOutputCol("authors_words").setPattern(",")
val tokJournal = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("journal").setOutputCol("journal_words")
val tokAbstract = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("abstract").setOutputCol("abstract_words")

//REMOVE STOPWORDS

val rTitle = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("title_words").setOutputCol("title_words_f")
val rAuthors = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("authors_words").setOutputCol("authors_words_f")
val rJournal = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("journal_words").setOutputCol("journal_words_f")
val rAbstract = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("abstract_words").setOutputCol("abstract_words_f")

println("Setting pipeline stages...")
val stages = Array(
  tokPubYear, tokTitle, tokAuthors, tokJournal, tokAbstract,
  rTitle, rAuthors, rJournal, rAbstract
)

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
pipeline.setStages(stages)

println("Transforming dataframe")
val model = pipeline.fit(papers)
papers = model.transform(papers)

papers.show(5)

//newDf = node df
val newDf = papers.select("id", "pubYear_words", "title_words_f", "authors_words_f", "journal_words_f", "abstract_words_f")
newDf.show(5)
newDf.describe().show()

val udf_join_cols = udf(join(_: Seq[String], _: Seq[String], _: Seq[String], _: Seq[String], _: Seq[String]))

val joinedDf = newDf.withColumn(
  "paper_data",
  udf_join_cols(
    newDf("pubYear_words"),
    newDf("title_words_f"),
    newDf("authors_words_f"),
    newDf("journal_words_f"),
    newDf("abstract_words_f"
    )
  )
).select("id", "paper_data")

joinedDf.show(5)
joinedDf.printSchema()
println(joinedDf.count())

// Word count to vector for each wiki content
val vocabSize = 1000000
val cvModel: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("paper_data").setOutputCol("features").setVocabSize(vocabSize)
  .setMinDF(10).fit(joinedDf)

val vectorizedDf = cvModel.transform(joinedDf).select(col("id"), col("features"))
vectorizedDf.show()
println("Total entries: "+vectorizedDf.count())

val mh = new MinHashLSH().setNumHashTables(3)
  .setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("hashValues")
val mhModel = mh.fit(vectorizedDf)

mhModel.transform(vectorizedDf).show()

// Self Join
val threshold = 0.95

val predictinsDF = mhModel.approxSimilarityJoin(vectorizedDf, vectorizedDf, 1,"JaccardDistance")
  .select("datasetA.id","datasetB.id","JaccardDistance").filter("JaccardDistance >= "+threshold)
  .withColumnRenamed("datasetA.id","nodeA_id")
  .withColumnRenamed("datasetB.id","nodeB_id")

predictinsDF.show()
predictinsDF.printSchema()
println("Total edges found: "+predictinsDF.count())  }
```

The origina graph is a file with to form of nodeAId, nodeBId. My results are in form of nodeAId, nodeBId, JaccardSimilarity. Botho of them are dataframes. How can I evaluate my results and get Accuracy or F1 score?

I have read how to find Accuracy and F1 score, so I tried to make a function to calculate them. My approach is the code bellow.

```
def getStats(spark:SparkSession,nodeDF:DataFrame, pairsDF:DataFrame, predictionsDF:DataFrame, graphDF:DataFrame): Unit ={
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

import spark.implicits._
val truePositives = graphDF.as("g").join(predictionsDF.as("p"),
  ($"g.nodeA_id" === $"p.nodeA_id" && $"g.nodeB_id" === $"p.nodeB_id") || ($"g.nodeA_id" === $"p.nodeB_id" && $"g.nodeB_id" === $"p.nodeA_id")
).count()

val df = pairsDF.as("p").join(graphDF.as("g"),
  ($"p.nodeA_id" === $"g.nodeA_id" && $"p.nodeB_id" === $"g.nodeB_id") || ($"p.nodeA_id" === $"g.nodeB_id" && $"p.nodeB_id" === $"g.nodeA_id")
).count()
println("True Positives: "+truePositives)

val falsePositives = predictionsDF.count() - truePositives
println("False Positives: "+falsePositives)

val trueNegatives = (pairsDF.count() - graphDF.count()) - falsePositives
println("True Negatives: "+trueNegatives)

val falseNegatives = graphDF.count()-truePositives
println("False Negatives: "+falseNegatives)

val truePN = (truePositives+trueNegatives).toFloat

val sum = (truePN + falseNegatives+ falsePositives).toFloat

val accuracy = (truePN/sum).toFloat
println("Accuracy: "+accuracy)

val precision = truePositives.toFloat / (truePositives+falsePositives).toFloat
val recall = truePositives.toFloat/(truePositives+falseNegatives).toFloat

val f1Score = 2*(recall*precision)/(recall+precision).toFloat
println("F1 score: "+f1Score) }
```

But, when I try to run it, it will never ends!! I dont know how to imrove this or to fix it in order to get tha Accuracy and F1 score. Is there any easier way to do this?

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can try to improve the execution performance:

1. **Caching:** If it fits to your setup, you can cache `nodeDF`, `pairsDF`, `predictionsDF` dataframes before calling `getStats` method. In the second part of your code, same action has been made on same dataframe for multiple times `graphDF.count()`. As spark follows lazy evaluation method, Repeated execution will take place, so you can keep this value at a variable so that it can be used.
2. **Find the culprit:** Basically i follow the way to improve performance. When the spark job is submitted the `sparkUI` will show the whole execution plan made by spark and it'll show which task is taking more time and other resources. You may need more resources or do some tuning so that less shuffling occurs between executors.
3. **Submit with optimal argument:** Before submitting the spark job, make sure that optimal resource uses from the setup. For more:[optimal resource allocation](http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/understanding-resource-allocation-configurations-spark-application/)

Comment: Your have right about your answer! It hepls me to improve my code. But, how I can evaluate my results ??